# How can i concatenate id of another user to a axios request url so as to get the chats with logged user usig MERN

Tags: reactjs, websocket, axios, chat, mern

**this is my conversation card which gets the details of the user logged in and the friend they are chatting with **
**I keep getting error 500 when i make the axios request and the two id of the users ie the current logged user and the friend id as well instead of returning the whole data of the two users**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MAVM.png)
**backend code**

```
router.get("/find/:id", verifyToken, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const userId = req.params.id
        const user = await User.findById(userId)
        res.status(200).json([user]);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }
});

router.get("/", verifyToken, async (req, res) => {
    const userId = req.query.userId;
    const preferred_name = req.query.preferred_name;
    try {
        const user = userId
            ? await User.findById(userId)
            : await User.findOne({ prefered_name: preferred_name });
        const { password, updatedAt, ...other } = user._doc;
        res.status(200).json(other);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json(error);
    }

})
```

**get conversation**

```
router.get('/:userId', async (req, res) => {

    //get the conversation
    try {
        const conversation = await Conversation.find({
            members: {
                $in: [req.params.userId]
            }
        })
        res.status(200).json(conversation)

    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json(error)
    }

})
```

```
    const [loggedUserId, setLoggedUserId] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        //find user id who is not equal to the current logged user id
        const friendId = conversation.members.find(
            (member) => member !== currentUser._id
        );
        const userId = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userData"));
        const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("accessToken"));

        //get loggedUser user
        const getUser = async () => {
            try {
                const res = await axios(
                    `${BASE_API_URL}/api/user/find/${userId.user._id}=` + friendId,
                    { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } }
                );
                console.log(res.data, "chat data");
                setLoggedUserId(res.data);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        };
        getUser();
    }, [currentUser, conversation]);
    //if no user found
    if (!loggedUserId) {
        return null;
    }
    return (
        <div className="conversationCard">
            <div className="main-ccard-conversation">
                <div className="conversationCard--profile d-flex">
                    <div className="conversationCard--profileIgm">
                        <img src={loggedUserId.image} alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="conversationCard--profileDetails">
                        <p className="profileDetails--name">{loggedUserId.full_name}</p>
                        <p className="profileDetails--distance">8 km Awway</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="profileDetails--austrology">
                    <p>{loggedUserId.zodiacSign}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**the index page where i call the conversation card**

```
  const [conversations, setConversations] = useState([]);
  const loggedUserData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userData") || "{}");
  const loggedUserId = loggedUserData?.user;
  useEffect(() => {
    const getConversation = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios(
          `${BASE_API_URL}/api/conversation/${loggedUserId._id}`
        );
        console.log(res.data);
        setConversations(res.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
    getConversation();
  }, [loggedUserId._id]);
  return (
    <div className="dashbaord">
      <div className="row g-0">
        <div className="sidebar-container">
          <MainSideBar />
        </div>
        <div className="col-sm-9 col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-md-10">
          <SideBarHeader />
          <div className="message-body">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
                <div className="message-show-chats">
                  <div className="chat-header">
                    <p>All Chats</p>
                  </div>
                  <div className="show-all-conversations">
                    {conversations.map((c) => (
                      <div key={c._id}>
                        <ConversationCard
                          conversation={c}
                          currentUser={loggedUserId}
                        />
                      </div>
                    ))}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="col-sm-8 col-lg-8">
                <div className="chat-header">
                  <p>Messages</p>
                </div>
                <Chat />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: You should post your back-end code handling the `/api/user/find` route

Comment: @lpizzinidev
  i have updated the backend code

Comment: the response i get shows userData of logged in user instead of the conversations of the user and freind